# Disjoints dense sets

Tags: general-topology

How can we define three disjoints dense sets? Then I have to define four and five disjoints dense sets and finally - infinity disjoints dense sets. Could you give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s not always possible: if a space has an isolated point, every dense subset must contain that point. Are you doing this in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, of course in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: *blink* Why *of course*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Consider sets of the form $x+\Bbb Q=\{x+q:q\in\Bbb Q\}$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ok, so for infinity disjoints dense sets we can take for example sets $\sqrt{x} + \mathbb{Q}$ where $x \in \mathbb{P}$ ($\mathbb{P}$ -primary numbers) ?

Comment: @Tomek: If you do that you have to show that if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q}$ is irrational, but yes, it can be done that way.

Comment: Ok, so the last question is, how can I prove that these sets are densinity? For example how prove that $\mbox{cl}(\sqrt{2} + \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$? For $\mathbb{Q}$ it was quite easy but here it may be problematic.

Comment: @Tomek: The fact that you’re working with translations makes it easy. You need to show that if $(a,b)$ is a non-empty open interval, then $(x+\Bbb Q)\cap(a,b)\ne\varnothing$; what do you know about the interval $(a-x,b-x)$?

Comment: Yes, it is clear. I thought as much, after I wrote my post. Thanks a lot for your helps - it was really helpful.

Comment: @Tomek: You’re welcome!